# define enum inside a struct which is inside a class

Tags: c++, class, struct, enums

I have seen people writing code like this... whats the point of it..

```
class Test 
{
public:

    struct MethodEnum
    {
        enum Enum
        {
             Method1,
             Method2
        };
    };
};
```

Comment: Before C++11, you could directly use enum values without prepending Enum like Enum::Method1 (you still can unless you use 'enum class'). While I am not 100% sure, this should force you to use MethoEnum::Method1 at least.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In pre-C++11, the labels of `enum` are not scoped (which means the labels were accessible without any qualification with the `enum` type!). So to make them *scoped*, programmers wrote those code. But in C++11, it is not needed, as you can define scoped-enum, using `enum class`.

So in C++11, your code would look like this:

```
class Test 
{
public:
    enum class MethodEnum
    {
             Method1,
             Method2
    };
};
```

Answer (score 1):

If there is more than one enumerated type defined in the same scope and two of those enumerated types have enumerations with the same name you get a conflict. This technique puts the names into separate scopes, possibly avoiding such a conflict by putting the names into separate scopes. That way, in member functions of `Test` you'd refer to the enumerators as `MethodEnum::Method1`, etc.

In C++11 you can get scoped names with `enum class`.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, you don't want the enumerators to pollute the surrounding scope; for example

```
enum Colour {
    Red,
    Yellow,
    Orange
};

enum Fruit {
    Apple,
    Physalis,
    Orange    // ERROR! already defined
};
```

Your example is the old-fashioned way to enclose them in a scope; these days, we have scoped enumerations (`enum class`) to do that more conveniently.

Answer (score 0):

It sets logical (or semantic) linkage between MethodEnum and the enumeration. So for example you can write

```
switch ( SomeExpression )
{
   case Test::MethodEnum::Method1
      // do some method1
      break;

   case Test::MethodEnum::Method2
      / do some method2
      break;

   default:
      std::cout << "There is no such a method" << std::endl;
      break;
}
```